# Обработка клика, двойного клика и перетаскивания по одному и тому же элементу

Tags: javascript, html, click

мне привели пример кода из другого вопроса, но почему то он не совсем корректно работает на мой взгляд:

```
$(function() {

  var doubleClickThreshold = 250;
  var lastClick = 0;
  var isDragging;
  var isDoubleClick = false;
  var mouseIsDown = false;
  $control = $("#controler");

  $control.click(function(){
    var thisClick = new Date().getTime();
    isDoubleClick = thisClick - lastClick < doubleClickThreshold; console.log(2);
    lastClick = thisClick; 
  });

  $control.mousedown(function() {
    mouseIsDown = true; 
  });

  $control.mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseIsDown = false;
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function() {
     if (mouseIsDown) {
       isDragging = true;
     }
  });

  if (isDoubleClick) {
    console.log(1);
  }
});
```

дело в том что - при двойном допустим клике - мне выводит сообщение console.log(2); т.е. конструкция  $control.click(function(){ - работает и если там выводить переменную  console.log(isDoubleClick) то она показывать false true false true - т.е. определяется, но в самом конце где идет

```
if (isDoubleClick) {
    console.log(1);
}
```

она почему то постоянно false - не выводится мой чек console.log(1);

подскажите пожалуйста что не так? это какая то локальная видимость переменных?

по тому что в конце мне бы хотелось сделать такую конструкцию:

```
if (isDoubleClick) {
    //действия для двойного клика
} else if (isDragging) {
    //действия для перетаскивания
} else {
    //действия одинарного клика
}
```

Comment: @Anastasia примерно права. Ответ уже дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950042/javascript-click-doubleclick-and-drag-in-the-same-element)

Comment: В двойном клике надо считать не количество нажатий, а и время между нажатиями. `lastClick` это время предыдущего клика, а не количество. Поэтому примерно. По поводу JS, у вас объявления переменных и математические операции в jQuery как-то по-другому работают?

Comment: @Anastasia Спасибо! Это почти помогло в принципе код работает но я не могу уловить что я делают не так - посмотрите пожалуйста, я изменил исходный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вам надо было разделить все эти евенты, при двойном клике не должно было срабатывать событие клика и аналогично и для перемещения элемента?
Вроде бы получилось как раз то, что вам было нужно:

```js
function makeEvent (elem, {onClick, onDblClick, onDrag}) {
  if (elem) {
    let timer;
    let pushme = false;
    let dragable = false;
    const el = document.querySelector(elem);
    el.onmouseup = () => pushme = false; 
    el.onmousedown = () => pushme = true;
    el.onclick = (e) => {
      if (!dragable) {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (timer) {
                onClick.call(e.target, e);
            }
          }, 250);
        }
       dragable = false;
    }
    el.ondblclick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearTimeout(timer); 
      timer = null;
      onDblClick.call(e.target, e);
    }
    el.onmousemove = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (pushme) {
          dragable = true;
          onDrag.call(e.target, e);
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer); 
            timer = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Использование
makeEvent('.btn', {
    onClick: function () {
      alert('click');
    },
    onDblClick: function () {
      alert('double click'); 
    },
     onDrag: function (e) {
      this.style.top = (e.pageY - (this.offsetHeight / 2)) + 'px';
      this.style.left = (e.pageX - (this.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
    }
})
```

```css
.btn {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  padding:10px; 
  text-align:center;
  background:#c54654;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" dragtable>click</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Приведенная ниже конструкция, к которой вы хотите прийти по сути является блоками исполняемого кода на определенное событие. В программистском народе это блоки называют функциями коллбеками (`callbacks`). Это такой шаблон асинхронного исполнения кода.

Не совсем понятно, почему вы разные коллбеки хотите проверять на `if else`.

Я уже частично ответил на ваш вопрос, почему вы никогда не увидите в консоли `1`. Вы инициализируете переменную `isDoubleClick` значением `false` и исполняете блок кода

```
if (isDoubleClick) {
    console.log(1);
}
```

единожды, когда скрипт загрузился и может быть исполнен (то есть синхронно/сейчас). А код слушателей событий, в котором `isDoubleClick` изменит свое значение, выполнится асинхронно (потом).

Возвращаясь к тому коду, что я вам скинул ранее в комментарии. Он работает таким образом, что вы определите двойной клик. Однако первый клик тоже отработает как событие.

Поэтому я написал немного другую структуру, которая будет четко генерировать нужное вам событие.

```js
const doubleClickThreshold = 250;

const clicker = document.getElementById('clicker');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function createClicker(clickFn, dblClickFn) {
    let timer;

    return function (event) {
        const context = this;

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            dblClickFn.call(context, event);
            timer = null;
            return;
        }

        timer = setTimeout(function (ctx) {
            timer = null;
            clickFn.call(ctx, event);
        }, doubleClickThreshold, context)
    }
}

function onClick(event) {
  output.innerHTML = 'click';
}

function onDoubleClick(event) {
  output.innerHTML = 'double click';
}

const clickHandler = createClicker(onClick, onDoubleClick);

clicker.onclick = clickHandler;
```

```html
<button id="clicker">Click</button>

<div>Сработал: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

В функцию `createClicker` надо передать две функции, одна вызовется на одинарный клик, вторая на двойной. Это заменит вашу `if else` конструкцию.

Этот способ тоже имеет определенный недостаток: событие одинарного клика будет иметь лаг в 250ms (`doubleClickThreshold`). Это то время, в течение которого мы ждем второй клик. И если его нет, то вызываем функцию клика.
Значение этого лага можно уменьшить. Тогда двойной клик надо будет осуществлять быстрее. В общем, найдите нужный вам баланс.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно ли как то ещё и отслеживание перетаскивания тут сделать, или всё таки идут ограничения самого языка? и это получится очень криво\

Comment: все зависит от того, какие действия вы хотите выполнить на перетаскивания. Если само перетаскивание, то это просто отдельные обработчики вешаются и все. Если вы хотите четко отделить клики от перетаскивания, то надо будет создать какую-то конструкцию, которая будет определять, двигается ли мышка в процессе клика или нет. Но там могут быть проблемы с обычным кликом: его надо будет делать четко удерживая курсор на месте. С одинарным кликом, это не проблема. Дабл клик станет задачей на ловкость

Comment: И да, в случае событий, ограничения может накладывать только браузер. Сам язык JS от таких понятиях, как `события/клики/запросы`, вообще не в курсе)

Answer (score 2):

Для отслеживание двойного клика можно использовать событие dblclick, а для перетягивания события: drag, dragend, dragover, dragleave, dragstart, dragenter, drop. Все эти события можно найти в глобальном объекте window.